# GWT Widget - definition

Tags: gwt, gwt-widgets

I am learning GWT Widget. Will it make sense if I say any concrete implementation that implements *com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget* is a widget? Does it holds always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget is a class, so any class that extends it is also a Widget.